# If a 2D dynamical system has two steady states, is it always the case that one steady state is stable and the other is unstable?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, dynamical-systems

If a system has two steady states, and given that one of them is unstable, can you infer that the other one is stable? (In a 2D dynamical system)

Comment: What kind of system did you have in mind? A simple 1D dynamical system?

Comment: A 2D dynamical system.

Comment: Not in 2D. They can both be saddles, or a source and a saddle.

Comment: @Conifold What about this: In an autonomous 2D dynamical system, if one of two fixed points is stable, can you infer that the other is not?

Comment: @Conifold I realize that saddles are in some sense neither stable nor unstable, so I was including saddles in "not stable." Let me try to be more precise: If there are two fixed points, and one is definitely a sink, must the other NOT be a sink?

Comment: Not sure, but I think still no. You can have them sitting inside limit cycles. If you rule out limit cycles, maybe.

Comment: Here is a 2D vector field / dynamical system that I believe is a counterexample to the original question: $x' = x(1-x)$, $y' = y$. This has an unstable fixed point at the origin and a saddle at $(x,y) = (1,0)$.

Comment: @JohnBarber: “Unstable” is defined as “not stable”, so saddles definitely count as unstable.

Comment: @HansLundmark Ah, OK. I was being overly cautious with nomenclature to avoid falling victim to a "clopen" scenario.

Comment: @JohnBarber: You can have two sinks; see my answer below.

Comment: @Conifold: It's possible without limit cycles; see my answer below.

Comment: @HansLundmark Thank you. I thought of two spiral sinks separated by a linear separatrix but could not get the global arrangement of flow lines clear enough in my head for such a case.

Comment: @Conifold: That was my first idea too, but I didn't find any particularly simple formulas at first. But I just realized that a simple modification of my other example works: $\dot x = 1-xy^2$, $\dot y = y(e^{2(x-1)}-y^2)$. ([Phase portrait on WA.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=StreamPlot%5B%7B1+-+x+y%5E2%2C+y+%28Exp%5B2+%28x+-+1%29%5D+-+y%5E2%29%7D%2C%7Bx%2C-1%2C3%7D%2C%7By%2C-2%2C2%7D%5D))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. Counterexample:

\begin{align}
\dot{x} &\;=\; x(1-x)\\
\dot{y} &\;=\; y
\end{align}

This has an unstable fixed point at $(x,y) = (0,0)$ and a saddle at $(x,y) = (1,0)$, as can be seen in the associated field of trajectories below.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Here's an example showing that you can even have two **sources** and no other equilibria:
$$
\dot x = x y^2 - 1
,\qquad
\dot y = y (y^2-1)
.
$$
The red and orange curves are the nullclines, where $\dot x=0$ and $\dot y=0$, respectively. They intersect at the equilibrium points $(x,y)=(1,\pm 1)$.
[image: Planar phase portrait with two sources]

And to answer some follow-up questions raised in the comments to the original question: if you negate the vector field, so that the flow goes in the opposite direction, you get a system with two **sinks** (not sitting inside limit cycles):
$$
\dot x = 1 - x y^2
,\qquad
\dot y = y (1-y^2)
.
$$

Comment: Great example. Another follow up question. There is no combination of isolated equilibria types that is prohibited in the plane, right? There is no meaningful Poincare-Hopf index theorem because of behavior at infinity?

Comment: @Conifold: I would suppose any combination is possible.